# domain socket fragmentation

Tags: c, sockets

I am using domain sockets (AF_UNIX) to communicate between two threads for inter process communication. This is chosen to work well with libev: I use it on the recv end of the domain socket. This works very well except that the data I am sending is constant 4864 bytes. I cannot afford to get this data fragmented. I always thought domain sockets won't fragment data, but as it turns out it does. When the communication is at its peak between the threads, I observe the following

```
Thread 1:
SEND = 4864 actual size = 4864

Thread 2:
READ = 3328 actual size = 4864

Thread 1:
SEND = 4864 actual size = 4864

Thread 2:
READ = 1536 actual size = 4864
```

As you can see, thread 2 received the data in fragments (3328 + 1536). This is really bad for my application. Is there anyway we can make it not fragment it? I understand that IP_DONTFRAG can be set to only AF_INET family? Can someone suggest an alternative?

Update: sendto code

```
ssize_t
socket_domain_writer_dgram_send(int *domain_sd, domain_packet_t *pkt) {

    struct sockaddr_un remote;
    unsigned long len = 0;
    ssize_t ret = 0;

    memset(&remote, '\0', sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(remote.sun_path, DOMAIN_SOCK_PATH, strlen(DOMAIN_SOCK_PATH));
    len  = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family) + 1;

    ret = sendto(*domain_sd, pkt, sizeof(*pkt), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    if (ret == -1) {
        bps_log(BPS_LOGGER_RD, ASL_LEVEL_ERR, "Domain writer could not connect send packets", errno);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: btw I use stream for this  
    if ((sock_d = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {

Comment: Why can't you have thread 2 block until it has received all 4864 bytes?

Comment: I was trying to avoid the locking only because the thread 1 is quite busy. I expected domain sockets to be 1 message format and hence I thought the blocking of write in thread1 will take care if there is no buffer. But that is not happening. Is it a good idea to move to DGRAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOCK_STREAM by definition doesn't preserve message boundaries. Try again with SOCK_DGRAM or SOCK_SEQPACKET:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html

On the other hand, consider that you may be passing messages larger than your architecture page size. For example, for amd64, a memory page is 4K. If that's a problem for any reason it might make sense to split the packets in 2.

Note however, that's not a real issue for the packets to arrive fragmented. It's common to have a packet assembler in the receiving end of the socket. What's wrong with implementing it ?

Comment: This is on freebsd. AFAIK there is no SOCK_SEQPACKET

Comment: It should, because SOCK_SEQPACKET is POSIX. http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=unix&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+9.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html

Comment: Link to POSIX documentation: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_10

Comment: ok, if I change SOCK_STREAM to SOCK_SEQPACKET other write and read functions can remain the same right?

Comment: just as I thought, it says Protocol not supported  if ((sock_d = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0)) == -1) {
        bps_log(BPS_LOGGER_RD, ASL_LEVEL_ERR, "Could not open domain socket", errno);
        return -1;
    }

Comment: You can either directly change it or if you hit some size limit, split the packet in two.Notice that the link I sent is FreeBSD manual page. FreeBSD suports it, as already commented, and also as it can be seen in the FreeBSD kernel source code: http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=ng9_Z2Z7kd2PviyEVmurSN08ey8&cid=UOVMcr1GJFY&s=%20%22SOCK_SEQPACKET%22&pp=0&fp=305042&ff=1&filterChecked=true&mp=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1&browser=Default#L165 It can also be seen live, I ran it here at home: http://pastebin.com/ZCb5rSAn Are you using an old version ? You might need to upgrade to FreeBSD 9.0.

Comment: Yeah, Iam actually using OSX, they are way back in terms of freebsd kernel and in the man page distributed with the OS this option is not give. Iam solving my problem by reducing the data Iam sending and moving to DGRAM. If my understanding is correct SOCK_SEQPACKET will help with the same buffer larger buffer but will take care of message boundary. What a lovely option :-) Thanks for your help anyways.

Answer (score 2):

`4864 + 3328 = 8192`. My guess is that you're transmitting two 4864-byte packets back to back in some cases, and it's filling an 8 KB kernel buffer somewhere. `IP_DONTFRAG` isn't applicable because IP is not involved here — the "fragmentation" you're seeing is happening via a completely different mechanism.

If all the data you're transmitting consists of packets, you would do well to use a datagram socket (`SOCK_DGRAM`) instead of a stream. This should make the `send()` block when the kernel buffer doesn't have sufficient space to store an entire packet, rather than allowing a partial write through, and will make each `recv()` return exactly one packet, so you don't need to deal with framing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but would that bring in unreliability and may be even messed up order of delivery?

Comment: No. UNIX domain socket datagrams are not subject to the same gotchas as UDP datagrams, as they are not transmitted over a network.

Comment: ok, now that I tied to send 4864 bytes using sendto() the following is the code

Comment: I get Domain writer could not connect send packets: Reason: Message too long ... it means 4864 is too long?